# How do you access variable in the link section of your directive in Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive that will generate the current year for copyright. How do I access the year variable in the link of the directive? I've tried everything, but nothing works.

```
.directive('copyrightYear', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var date = new Date();
            var year = date.getFullYear();
        },
        template: ''
    };
})
```

Comment: Are you trying to access year from the template for the directive?

Comment: that looks like it would generate a year variable, but you don't appear to be using it anywhere.

Comment: @Travis Yes, I tried {{ year }} and {{ copyRight.year }}. Year returns nothing, copyright.year returns NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to the scope

```
.directive('copyrightYear', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var date = new Date();
            scope.year = date.getFullYear();
        },
        template: '{{year}}'
    };
});
```

Comment: I was going to answer the same. ^1